# Parameters not being read even though they appear to be passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, parameters

I'm making a form that creates more than one record for the user depending on how many items the user decides to check off in the form using checkboxes.

Currently, I'm running into an error where `param is missing or the value is empty: itemrecord` even though in the log, it appears that `params` are passing through:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m2NMruoFRr6lpsuVMK9UthlY0bsJsPmf1LWce2uKaH4=", ":item_name"=>["Backpack", "Water filter"], "commit"=>"Go!"}
```

Model relationship is that a `User has_many :inventories`

Controller code:

```
def create
    @itemrecord = @current_user.inventories.build

    items_to_be_saved = []
    inventory_params.each do |i|
        items_to_be_saved << ({ :signup_id => @current_user.id,  :item_name => i })
    end

    if Inventory.create items_to_be_saved
        flash[:success] = "Thanks!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render new_inventory_path
    end
end

def inventory_params
  params.require(:itemrecord).permit(:item_name)
end
```

View code:

```
          <%= form_for @itemrecord do |f| %>

            <!-- In case you're wondering, the @wishlist below is basically a hash of categories of items and items. This hash is updated in the controller, and then used by multiple views to create the same table of items. -->

            <% @wishlist.each do |category, list| %>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group box">
                  <h5> <%="#{category}"%> </h5>
                    <% list.each do |thing| %>
                        <%= check_box_tag ":item_name[]", "#{thing}" %>
                      </br>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>  
            <% end %>

              <%= f.submit "Go!", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %>
            </div>

          <% end %>
```

By the way I also tried changing `:item_name` to `:item_names` to account for the array based on what else I read on SO, but that didn't fix it either

Comment: Changing your `inventory_params` to this `params.require(:inventory).permit(:item_name)` will work.

Comment: Per what @JKen13759 said below, that won't work either

Comment: @James did you end up trying my answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: kind of sort of... i needed to do a `params.permit[:item_name]` but then realized i actually needed a whole new attribute. but i liked your answer, and it did help, so I have accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `inventory_params` function. You're saying that you require an `itemrecord`, and permit an `item_name` attribute. Observe:

```
def inventory_params
  params.require(:itemrecord).permit(:item_name)
end
```

However, in the parameters being passed, there is no reference to an `itemrecord` object whatsoever, but there is a reference to `item_name`. A quick change to your `inventory_params` method, removing the `:itemrecord` requirement and instead requiring `:item_name`, will fix your issue.

```
def inventory_params
  params.require(:item_name)
end
```

While this isn't necessarily the best way to go about doing this (I'd suggest reading up on your [Active Record Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)), it should solve your issue.